# Task Scheduler not running interactive batch file/ How to make batch file non interactive

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to run a batch file with task scheduler.
The batch file is utilizing SecureFX to transfer a file between servers via cmd line. The problem is the command opens a cmd window and displays info about the file transfer. I think task scheduler will not run this correctly in 'Run whether the user is logged in or not' mode because of the open cmd window.

The thing is I need it to run in 'Run whether the user is logged in or not' mode.
I have tried using vbs script with the following:

```
Set Shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Shell.ShellExecute "my.bat", , , "runas", 0
```

This when run by itself does the trick, .bat runs no cmd window, but when run through task scheduler I get a 0x41301 result, which apparently means the task is already running, but the task was not running beforehand.

Contents of my.bat:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %% in ('date /T') do set MyDate=%%a%%b%%c
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=: " %%a in ("%TIME%") do set MyTime=%%a%%b%%c
set LOGFILE=D:\logfilelocation\sfxcl_log_%MyDate%_%MyTime%.txt

sfxcl /NOPROMPT /LOG "%LOGFILE%" D:\path_to_files_for_transfer\rt_*.zip sftp://user:password@hostname//destinationFolder:/
```

Task Scheduler Settings:

- User: System
- Run with Highest Privileges - On
- Run whether user is logged on or not - On
- Triggered daily - every day 09:00
- Actions, in Program/script field:
- D:\location_bat_file\my.bat
- Add Arguments and start in fields are empty.
- The location of the batch and vbs files I am trying to use are local.

Can someone help with this please?

Comment: Does the command `sfxcl` work directly from a new [tag:cmd] window when 'Run as administrator', _(Command Prompt with current directory as C:\Windows\System32)_? If not, you'll need to use its full path or ensure that its location is listed under the System Environment variable named `PATH`.

Comment: @Compo yeah it works from a new command window